# How to check if there are some recordings share the same name, but they have different types in mysql

Tags: mysql

There is a table with 97972561 rows (recordings) and 4 columns (attributes). The format looks like:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| PMID | SUBJECT_NAME| SUBJECT_TYPE| Sentence_ID |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I would like to check if there are some subjects share the same name with different types.
For example, there are three recordings in a table:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| PMID | SUBJECT_NAME| SUBJECT_TYPE| Sentence_ID |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1    | Bob         | F           | 1           |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2    | Bob         | B           | 2           |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 3    | Bob         | F           | 3           |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I do not care about how many cases, just want to check if there are two recordings with the same subject_name, but different subject_type. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would aggregate by subject name and then assert that the max and min types are different:

```
SELECT SUBJECT_NAME
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY SUBJECT_NAME
HAVING MIN(SUBJECT_TYPE) <> MAX(SUBJECT_TYPE);
```

Note the way I wrote the `HAVING` clause leaves it *sargable*, meaning that any index on `SUBJECT_TYPE` could potentially be used.  The following index might speed up this query:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (SUBJECT_NAME, SUBJECT_TYPE);
```